# Not returning min but returning Max

Tags: javascript, max, min

I want to know what I am doing wrong, the code below is not returning the minimum number in the array

```
var phoneNumbers = [ 
   { "id": 1, "phoneNo": "0758709939" },
   { "id": 1, "phoneNo": "0158703431" }
 ]
```

below is the code I wrote to return the min value

```
return Array.from(phoneNumbers)
   .map((arr) => arr.phoneNo)
   .reduce((prev, curr) => prev > curr ? prev : curr, 0)
```

Can somebody help me look at it?

Comment: how about you sort the results on basis of phoneNo and then pick the first element of the array?

Comment: I think you should invert this condition `prev > curr ? prev : curr`.

Comment: @UmairAbid Bad idea, sorting is `O(N log N)`, an `O(N)` solution is better

Comment: If you wrote the code then you should know about the comparison operators `<` and `>` as well as the ternary operator (`?;`). And you should also know how to fix your problem yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have tried every option but it is returning the maximum value instead. I asked here because I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your picking of values depends on the expression `prev > curr ? prev : curr`. You want to reverse that one. Now there are two ways of doing that: Either change the condition; Or switch the returned values.

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong condition in the callback given to `reduce`

```
return Array.from(this.phoneNumbers)
   .map((arr) => arr.phoneNo)
   .reduce((prev, curr) => Math.min(prev, curr), 0)
```

Comment: `Math.min` will convert strings to number, so you'll loose leading zero(s)